# Is there a resize function in Python to resize an image as the tf.image.resize_images function of TensorFlow?

Tags: python, image, numpy, tensorflow, scikit-image

I have a 4D ndarray of image data, which is organized as [NumberOfImages, **RowsOfImage**, **ColumnsOfImage**, ChannelsOfImage].

Now I want to resize the images in the 4D ndarray to the new size, which is with the size of [NumberOfImages, **NewRowsOfImage**, **NewColumnsOfImage**, ChannelsOfImage], while the other dimensions remain unchanged.

I know there is a function **tf.image.resize_images** in TensorFlow to do this. If the new image is larger than the original one, the new image will be filled with new pixels using the Bilinear interpolation or Nearest neighbor interpolation.

However, the ndarray of image data was converted to a Tensor object of TensorFlow after resized. Then I have to convert it back to a ndarray. These procedures will cost massive time.

I have tried **skimage.transform.resize**, but this function seems to resize an 2D image data. If I use this function, I have to use a **for loop** which will cost enormous time too.

So is there a resize function in Python which is as same as the tf.image.resize_images function of TensorFlow? If not, could anybody give me some advice to solve my problem?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

use `numpy.resize`. See below example. All images has the same shape (in this case 768 x 1024 x 3). In this example, I switched the row number with the column number. `im_all` is your 4d array.

```
from scipy.misc import imread
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f = r"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Lighthouse.jpg"
im0 = imread(f)
f = r"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\koala.jpg"
im1 = imread(f)
f = r"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\tulips.jpg"
im2 = imread(f)
f = r"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\desert.jpg"
im3 = imread(f)
im_all = np.array([im0, im1, im2, im3])
im_all_b = np.resize(im_all, [im_all.shape[0], im_all.shape[2], im_all.shape[1], im_all.shape[3]])
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(im_all_b[1])
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(im_all[1])
plt.show()
```

Here is an example with interpolation (default is `bilinear`, see: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imresize.html) with memory usage optimization:

```
from scipy.misc import imread, imresize
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f = r"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Lighthouse.jpg"
im0 = imread(f)
f = r"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\koala.jpg"
im1 = imread(f)
f = r"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\tulips.jpg"
im2 = imread(f)
f = r"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\desert.jpg"
im3 = imread(f)
im_all = np.array([im0, im1, im2, im3])
for i in range(im_all.shape[0]):
    temp = im_all[0, :, :, :].copy()
    im_all = np.delete(im_all, 0, 0)
    temp = imresize(temp, (temp.shape[0]+200, temp.shape[1]+200, 3))
    temp = np.expand_dims(temp, axis=0)
    try:
        im_all_b = np.vstack([im_all_b, temp])
    except NameError:
        im_all_b = temp

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(im_all_b[1])
plt.show()
```

In the above example I add 200 pixels to each of x and y axis.

Comment: Thank you. But the operation in your example is just the reshape of an image. Then It seems that the np.resize function can resize the image to a larger image, However, it does not resize it using the common interpolation method, such as the Nearest neighbor interpolation method like the function tf.image.resize_images of TensorFlow. It just  filles the original image with repeated copies of it. I'm sorry this is not what I want. Anyway, thank you all the same.

Comment: Yes, it works this time. But your program used a **for loop** which took massive time since our image data contain hundreds of thousands of images. Besides, when the image data were rescaled to float format ranging from 0 to 1, there will be an error which shows the format was not supported. Anyway, thank you very much for your kind help.